# Beautifulsoup fail to read page

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urlopen

I am trying the following:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/Property.aspx?prop_id=312669'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())
print soup
```

The `print` statement above shows the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>Travis Property Search</title>
<style type="text/css">
      body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; }
      h1 { font-size: 50px; }
      body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }
      #article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }
      a { color: #dc8100; text-decoration: none; }
      a:hover { color: #333; text-decoration: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="article">
<h1>Please try again</h1>
<div>
<p>Sorry for the inconvenience but your session has either timed out or the server is busy handling other requests. You may visit us on the the following website for information, otherwise please retry your search again shortly:<br /><br />
<a href="http://www.traviscad.org/">Travis Central Appraisal District Website</a> </p>
<p><b><a href="http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/?cid=1">Click here to reload the property search to try again</a></b></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to access the url however through the browser on same computer so the server is definitely not blocking my IP. I don't understand what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get some cookies first, then you can visit the url.
Although this can be done with `urllib2` and `CookieJar` , i recommend `requests` :

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url1 = 'http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/?cid=1'
url = 'http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/Property.aspx?prop_id=312669'
ses = requests.Session()
ses.get(url1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(ses.get(url).content)
print soup.prettify()
```

Note that `requests` is not a standard lib, you'll have to insall it.
If you want to use `urllib2` :

```
import urllib2
from cookielib import CookieJar

url1 = 'http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/?cid=1'
url = 'http://propaccess.traviscad.org/clientdb/Property.aspx?prop_id=312669'
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.open(url1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(url).read())
print soup.prettify()
```

Comment: `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` shouldn't it be `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` ?

Comment: @MD. Khairul Basar yes, that's how i usually import it, but it works either way.

Comment: why did you have to import cookies .. other examples I have tried never needed cookies

Comment: The site won't display the page unless you send cookies. You 'll get the same html response you posted in your question if you visit the page with a browser and delete the cookies. Also consider using `requests` , it makes things much easier.

Comment: (1) how did you figure it was cookies problem? (2) how did you figure cookie address?

Comment: If you open the page with a browser ( without cookies ) it gives you the `url1` ( "Click here" ) i used in my code. If you follow the link it gives you cookies ( ASP.NET_SessionId ) and then you can visit the `url` .